# How to duplicate each row in sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Suppose we have a query

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY id
```

which results in

```
id | title
-----------
 1 | 'ABC'
 2 | 'DEF'
 3 | 'GHI'
```

How could I modify given select statement to have each row duplicated in the result set like this:

```
id | title
-----------
 1 | 'ABC'
 1 | 'ABC'
 2 | 'DEF'
 2 | 'DEF'
 3 | 'GHI'
 3 | 'GHI'
```

Comment: This is the first time I've seen someone actually *want* a Cartesian join instead of trying to remove one ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cross join to a row generator, the numeric value indicates how many duplicates per original you want.

```
select *
from my_table 
     cross join
       (select null
        from dual
        connect by level <= 2)
order by id
```

Comment: this is unbelievable elegant.

Comment: You should be able to use `select my_table.*` too, so that the extra column used as a generator is not shown.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `union all`, but I like using `cross join`:

```
select *
from MyTable cross join
     (select 1 from dual union all select 2 from dual) n
order by id;
```

The reason I like the `cross join` is in the case where `MyTable` is really some complicated subquery.  Although the query optimizer *might* evaluate it only once, you can't really depend on that fact.  So the performance should be better in this case.

Comment: Thank you! Thats perfect (as can be in sql)! Why not use UNION instead of UNION ALL in this case? May it cause problems or there's no difference?

Comment: @FloppyRetop . . . Basically, you should *never* using `union` unless you want to incur the specific overhead of removing duplicate values.

Comment: I agree it's so in general case, but just was curious if the 'all' word really matters in this case with selecting single row from dual

Comment: @FloppyRetop . . . I assume it does duplicate elimination in all cases.  It is rather hard for the complier to know whether or not there are duplicates -- especially because duplicates within tables are removed as well as between tables.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
 SELECT * FROM my_table 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM my_table
 ORDER BY id
```

Comment: You need to use `UNION ALL`, otherwise it will remove duplicates.

Comment: Not bad. And what if I want 5 duplicates per each original?

Comment: You can add UNION ALL SELECT * FROM my_table as many times as you want

Comment: @Brendan, I don't want to perform multiple selects returning the same result. It can be slow.